# Program type already present: androidx.appcompat.R$anim

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Hi hope you all are fine and in good health.
I am facing this issue when i am trying to generate apk file.
This issue is occuring after integration of printing library in libs folder.
When i use  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' then it gives this error "Program type already present: androidx.appcompat.R$bool"

Thanks.

My gradle file dependencies:

```
 `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.Cutta:GifView:1.4'
implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.3.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0"
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6`
```

Answer (score 0):

`Program type already present` this error occurs whenever your project has the repeating libraries or same library .

As per official [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes):

*This error typically occurs due to one of the following circumstances:*

*A binary dependency includes a library that your app also includes as a direct dependency. For example, your app declares a direct dependency on Library A and Library B, but Library A already includes Library B in its binary.
To resolve this issue, remove Library B as a direct dependency.
Your app has a local binary dependency and a remote binary dependency on the same library.
To resolve this issue, remove one of the binary dependencies.*

I think in your case the appcompat is present `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` in your gradle as well as JAR file in the libs folder.

Try removing the jar, this will resolve.

And additionally in your gradle, this library is present twice, remove and sync the project again.

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4'
```